# How to make matplotlib.pyplot subplots that overlap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am learning how to use subplots. For example:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(221)
plt.subplot(222)
plt.subplot(223)

plt.show()

plt.close(1)
```

I am getting 3 subplots in figure1

Now I want to make a large subplot with the other subplots within the first one. I tried:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplot(222)
plt.subplot(223)
```

But the first subplot disappears.

My question: is it possible to overlap subplots?

thank you

Comment: You've accepted an answer that doesn't answer the question, while there is another answer that DOES.

Comment: Sorry P i , not sure if I understand your complaint. All answers were good, and I vote them all up. However, the one I accepted is the one that solved my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use `plt.subplots()` to create overlapping subplots. Also, `plt.subplot2grid` will not work.

However, you can create them using the `figure.add_subplot()` method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.add_subplot(222)
fig.add_subplot(223)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Both methods are very interesting (add_subplot and add_axes). But  add_subplot is exactly the answer I was looking for. Is there any advantage using one or the other?

Comment: They are very different. `add_subplot` creates an axes according to some grid. The advantange is that the grid may later be modified and the axes sticks to it, e.g. one can call `plt.tight_layout()` or `plt.subplots_adjust`. In contrast `add_axes` puts the axes at the position specfied. It will then stay where it is. This can be an advantage or a disadvantage depending on the case.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a total control of the subplots size and position, use Matplotlib [`add_axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=add_axes#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) method instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.85])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.4, 0.6, 0.45, 0.3])
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.65])

ax1.text(0.01, 0.95, "ax1", size=12)
ax2.text(0.05, 0.8, "ax2", size=12)
ax3.text(0.05, 0.9, "ax3", size=12)

plt.show()
```

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes.html) to create an inset axes on an existing figure. 
I added a `print` statement at the end which shows a list of two axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator as mpl_il

plt.plot() 

ax2 = mpl_il.inset_axes(plt.gca(), width='60%', height='40%', loc=6)
ax2.plot()

print(plt.gcf().get_axes())
plt.show()
```

[image: Creating inset axes on existing figure]