# Plot/remove overlay at mouse position upon mouse down/up in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, interactive

I'm working with Python/matplotlib. Ideally inside VSCode's .ipynb editor, although I may have to settle for running from the CLI.

Suppose I plot 2 axes.
Now every time I mouse-down on one of them, it draws a fresh overlay plot centered on the mouse position.
Mouse-up removes the plot.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Gottit.

I'm working in VSCode, and I needed this to render plots to a standalone window (otherwise I can't get 'interactive' -- if anyone can achieve inline-interactive in VSCode, please comment):

```
%matplotlib
```

First make a couple of plots:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1) ;  line1, = ax1.plot(range(5))
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2) ;  line2, = ax2.plot(range(5,-1,-1))
```

Now the hard part:

```py
# Returns a new axis object which is inset into the passed `ax` axis
#    centered at `x` (w.r.t. the axis' coord system)
def add_inset(ax, x):
    X0, Y0, W, H = 0, 1, 2, 3  # for indexing rectangle objects

    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    x01 = (x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin)
    w = 0.2  # overlay should be 20% the width of the axis
    ロoverlay_in_ax = [x01-w/2, 0.1, w, 0.8]  # rect for overlay within ax (values 0 to 1)

    overlay_absolute_origin_px = ax.transAxes.transform(
        (ロoverlay_in_ax[X0], ロoverlay_in_ax[Y0]))

    overlay_absolute_origin = ax.figure.transFigure.inverted(
        ).transform(overlay_absolute_origin_px)

    ロax_in_fig = ax.get_position()  # box of axis within figure (values 0 to 1)

    ロoverlay_in_fig = [
        overlay_absolute_origin[X0],
        overlay_absolute_origin[Y0],
        ロax_in_fig.width * ロoverlay_in_ax[W],
        ロax_in_fig.height * ロoverlay_in_ax[H]
        ]

    return fig.add_axes(ロoverlay_in_fig)
```

```py
def on_down(event):
    on_click(event, 'down')

def on_up(event):
    on_click(event, 'up')

ax_inset = None
def on_click(event, updown):
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

    ax = event.inaxes
    print(updown, x, y, ax, ax==ax1, ax==ax2)
    print(event.x, event.y)

    if updown == 'down':
        line2.set_color('red')
        global ax_inset
        ax_inset = add_inset(ax, x)
        ax_inset.plot([1]*5)

    else:
        print('off')
        ax_inset.remove()

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()  # was .draw(), recommended by gitter people

plt.connect('button_press_event', on_down)
plt.connect('button_release_event', on_up)
```

Here's the result:
[image]

---

Resources:

https://github.com/matplotlib/interactive_tutorial <- tutorial #6 covers 'interactive'

[How to make matplotlib.pyplot subplots that overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800584/how-to-make-matplotlib-pyplot-subplots-that-overlap)

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c06e8709dde6504d396349c0c80ef019c88c3927/lib/matplotlib/backends/web_backend/nbagg_uat.ipynb

https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/interactive.html <-- recommends `%matplotlib` which works, even tho' it's not inline

[Matplotlib coordinates tranformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932908/matplotlib-coordinates-tranformation)